# Stanford CoreNLP: How do you integrate a standard, but Russian-trained NER model with completely custom models for lemmatisation?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am currently working on adapting a coreference tagging algorithm to Russian, as part of my university project, based on Stanford CoreNLP. For the most part, it was easy enough: there already exist Russian models for lemmatisation and PoS-tagging. However, there was no NER model for the language, at least based on CoreNLP, and as such, I had to train such a model myself using CoreNLP's statistical methods.

The problem's in adapting this new trained NER model to the lemmatisation and PoS-tagging models. While my model was purely statistical and was still based on the original CoreNLP code, the two other ones are completely different. Therefore, I cannot actually make my NER integrate them. How can you accomplish that? The relevant code is:

```
props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,custom.lemma,custom.morpho,custom.ner,depparse, mention, coref");
props.setProperty("pos.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/russian-ud-pos.tagger");
props.setProperty("customAnnotatorClass.custom.lemma", "edu.stanford.nlp.international.russian.process.RussianLemmatizationAnnotator");
props.setProperty("custom.lemma.dictionaryPath", "edu/stanford/nlp/international/russian/process/dict.tsv");
props.setProperty("customAnnotatorClass.custom.morpho", "edu.stanford.nlp.international.russian.process.RussianMorphoAnnotator");
props.setProperty("customAnnotatorClass.custom.ner", "edu.stanford.nlp.international.russian.process.RussianMorphoAnnotator");
props.setProperty("custom.morpho.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/russian-ud-mf.tagger");
props.setProperty("ner.model", "C:/Users/Admin/eclipse-workspace/Coreference-Evaluation-master/libs/russian-new-model.ser.gz");
props.setProperty("depparse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/nndep.rus.model.wiki.txt.gz");
props.setProperty("depparse.language", "russian");
props.setProperty("parse.maxlen", "100");
props.setProperty("ssplit.eolonly", "true");
props.setProperty("tokenize.whitespace","true");
props.setProperty("coref.removeSingletonClusters","false");
pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
System.out.println(pipeline);
```

Before you suggest I change the algorithm altogether: my knowledge of Java as of now is not good enough to make such radical changes to the already existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tag your NER training data with your custom lemmatizer and part-of-speech tagger.  Also make sure the tokenization is the same as you will be using at test time.  Then train the NER model with the predicted lemmas and part-of-speech tags.  This is assuming you are using those as features in your NER model.

If your NER training data doesn't have part-of-speech or lemma data in it, the pipeline should just work fine, as the NER model won't use those features for its decisions.  I don't believe the NER models we distribute use those features for example.

Comment: The problem is that the standard NER model demands lemmatisation: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: annotator "ner" requires annotation "LemmaAnnotation". The usual requirements for this annotator are: tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma"

Comment: That is because you have ner.useSUTime and ner.applyNumericClassifiers set to true.  Those should be set to false.